# How can I change the default font-size without having .height return inaccurate values

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the default font-size by applying css to the body and html like this:

```
body, html { font-size: 10px , font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
```

However in doing this when trying to size a scrollable area when a dialog is opened I am getting scrollbars when I wouldn't expect to, here is a jsFiddle showing the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/JJQMF/

Just to show that without the css everything works fine here is a jsFiddle that does not include the font-size css and everything works as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/JJQMF/35/

So, is there a way to set this css that won't effect the results of height? Or is there a bug in jQuery's height function that is returning a value that is inaccurate, even though it appears like the number returned should work? Any other suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

**Update:** The dialog isn't even necessary here is an even more reduced jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwaddell/k7kDD/

Comment: The height is accurate as far as I can tell: http://i.imgur.com/SEg6r79.png. For the record, the scrollbar appears on both for me (using Chrome).

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Hmm, I wonder if there is a slight bug in .height right now then. For the record I tested in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `#Select_ScrollContent` overflow to hidden

```
#Select_ScrollContent{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will get rid of the scroll bars but still allow you to have the `overflow: auto` on the `#Select_ScrollContainer` So if you need to append extra content or have longer list it will still allow for scrolling. To see what I mean just uncomment the append statement in the following [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/JJQMF/41/).

Comment: Very interesting, I'll admit I am not great with css, this leads me to believe the scrollbar was actually on the #Select_ScrollContent div. I never want it to scroll so setting it to hidden definitely makes sense to me. Do you know how the browser decides to give the height to #Select_ScrollContent? I am seeing the two inner divs have a height of 26px, margin of 2px, and a border of 2px, how does that get to be 78px without your fix and 80px with it?

Comment: What you were experiencing is known as [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fmargin_collapsing). The first `h3` top margin was collapsing so that it was outside of its parent `div` which in this case was `#Select_ScrollContent`. So therefore it wasn't being applied to the height of the `div`. Adding `overflow: hidden` fixes this. :) –

Answer (score 0):

Withou setting `#Select_ScrollContainer` overflow property:

http://jsfiddle.net/JJQMF/37/

Comment: Yeah, I thought about dynamically setting that yesterday, I could have a lot more than two items listed in my application so sometimes I'll need the overflow property.  The only problem I have with that is I am not sure it fixes my root issue but will only fix the issue on this specific dialog. I may end up going this way though.